# HTTP Post request is not de-serializing correctly for JSON Hash

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

My ASP.NET MVC action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(APIRequest request)
{
}
```

My class looks like:

```
public class APIRequest
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Atts { get; set; } 

    public APIRequest()
    {

    }
}
```

On the front-end I am sending the AJAX call like so:

```
 var atts = {
        'userId' : '10203',
        'foo': '1',
        'bar': '2',
        'some-invalid-identifier': '3'
    };



 $.ajax({
        url: "/path/to/save",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(atts),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function(r) {

        },
        success: function(r) {

        }
    });
```

When I set a breakpoint in my controller, the request variable Atts (dictionary) property is always null.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is not providing the `Atts` property. The way you are sending it, the model binder will be looking for 4 properties - userId, foo, bar and some-invalid-identifier. This will work:

```
{
   "Atts" : { "userId" : "10203",
              "foo": "1",
              "bar": "2",
              "some-invalid-identifier": "3"
            }
}
```